# Finding the impulse response from the integral

Tags: control-system, signal-processing

I'm trying to solve the part (a) of the following:

[image: se respo]

I know that:
$$
y(t) = \int_0^1 \! \delta (t-\lambda ) \mathrm{d}\lambda
$$

But I'm not sure how to proceed from that.

Comment: To determine if a system is causal, this requires \$t\geq t_0\$... so what's \$t_0\$ and what's its sign in \$y(t)\$? Now to determine if it's BIBO stable, again, look at the equation. For something to be BIBO stable, this equation has to be true: \$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} | h(t) | dt < \infty \$ .... Is that true?

Comment: Yes but first of all I need to figure out h(t)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to solve for 
$$y(t) = \int_0^1 \! \delta (t-\lambda ) \mathrm{d}\lambda$$

But notice that
$$\int_0^1 \! \delta (t) \mathrm{d}t =1,$$
and also
$$\int_0^1 \! \delta (T-t) \mathrm{d}t = \begin{cases}&1,& 0 \leq T \leq 1\\ & 0,&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Since you have that \$T\$ term varying in your equation

$$y(t) = \int_0^1 \! \delta (t-\lambda ) \mathrm{d}\lambda$$
it will depend on \$t\$ the same way as it depended on \$T\$.

Comment: Your 2nd equation (integral 0..1 of impulse) is improper.  The initial limit of 0 falls "at" the impulse function.   Sometimes you'll see limits of "0+" or "0-" to disambiguate.  In either case, what's meant is "the limit as A approaches 0 from the left" or "...from the right" -- if that limit exists.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the limits on the integrals should be -infinity to +infinity.  This will give you y(t) vs. x(t) for all t.  That said, this problem is trying to confuse you by using 0 and 1 as the integral limits.  "No problem" -- change the limits to -inf and +inf, and insert a "window" function in the integrand:
$$
y(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x(t-\lambda) W(\lambda)d\lambda\,.
$$
where the "window" function W(.) is zero everywhere except within [0,1] where it is 1 (unity).  Now that it's in a familiar (canonical) form, we can realize:

- The transfer function is just W(.) as I have described above!  (mentally substitute the letter *h* for the *W* and you see it's just the general formula for any LTI network).
- Since h(t) (which we now know) is zero for t within -infinity to zero, the network is clearly causal.  A non-causal network is always recognizable as its transfer function would have a nonzero response prior to t = 0 (which our h(t) does not exhibit).
- Because the transfer function h(t) has finite area (is time bounded); i.e., after t=1 it becomes zero), the network is BIBO stable.  (Think: Suppose I tried to make this network blow up -- I can't because no matter what input you send to this network, it will only respond for 1 second to your input [the width of the nonzero portion of h(t)].  Thus, to make its output diverge, you would have to present an input that is infinite "energy" within a 1-second interval, which is *not* a BI (bounded input) by definition.

To directly answer your actual query:  Remember always *always* *always*, by definition:
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(t-\lambda) ANY(\lambda) d\lambda\ = ANY(t) $$
That is, the integral disappears completely (this is called the "sifting" property of the (Dirac) impulse function).  This is ONLY true for the integral limits -infinity to +infinity.

So your equation
$$ y(t) = \int_0^1 \delta(t-\lambda) d\lambda $$
is just 
$$ y(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \delta(t-\lambda) W(\lambda) d\lambda = W(t) $$

I always found it beneficial to *do whatever is needed* to make the integral limits the entire real axis.  So many of these types of problems simplify when you do that.

A *further* benefit of the (doubly-infinite axis of integration) is that you can interchange the functions in the integrand like so:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(t-\lambda)W(\lambda) d\lambda = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(\lambda)W(t-\lambda) d\lambda
$$
without changing variables (just do it mentally).  This can help too.

Answer (score 0):

Your sytem's output now = the integral of the input calculated from now to now-1.

The impulse peaks at t=0. If t=0 happens to fit into time window now...now-1 then the output is=1, otherwise it's =0.

I's causal because output now doesn't need anything from the future, only from now to now-1

It's BIBO stable because bounded input cannot generate unbounded integral over a limited time range. Just in this case the integral at now must stay between the max and min input values during now....now-1 (assumed dimensionless time)